# Why does the argument list_only do on Walker_Category_Checklist::start_el?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms, walker

On the post edit screen there is the meta box for categories that utilizes the `Walker_Category_Checklist` class to create the category checklist within the meta box. One of the conditions (line 90 of `/wp-admin/includes/class-walker-category-checklist.php` in WP 5.7.1) is:

```php
if ( ! empty( $args['list_only'] ) ) {
  // do some things
}
```

What is `list_only`? It does not appear on the dev reference for [`Walker_Category_Checklist::start_el`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category_checklist/start_el/) nor [`wp_terms_checklist()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_terms_checklist/).

And it appears only twice in WP core:

- `includes/template.php`

  - line 120: `$args['list_only'] = ! empty( $parsed_args['list_only'] );`
- `wp-admin/includes/class-walker-category-checklist.php`

  - line 90 - `if ( ! empty( $args['list_only'] ) ) {` as shown fully above.

Here is the whole if clause starting at 90:

```php
if ( ! empty( $args['list_only'] ) ) {
    $aria_checked = 'false';
    $inner_class  = 'category';

    if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'], true ) ) {
        $inner_class .= ' selected';
        $aria_checked = 'true';
    }

    $output .= "\n" . '<li' . $class . '>' .
      '<div class="' . $inner_class . '" data-term-id=' . $category->term_id .
      ' tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="' . $aria_checked . '">' .
      /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
      esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name, '', '' ) ) . '</div>';
```

Comment: Well what is `// do some things`? It would be for that, no?

Comment: Yes, it would be. I've added it to the original question as the bottom...I think it makes it so that the category item cannot be selected...but I'm wondering when exactly this would ever get called?

Comment: If you wanted a read-only checklist, presumably. WordPress does not appear to use it itself.